# mongoengine - Query on ListField of EmbeddedDocumentField

Tags: python, django, mongodb, model, mongoengine

I use mongoengine with Django and python.

This is my code:

```
class Chambre(EmbeddedDocument):
    max_personne = IntField(default=0)
    prix = IntField(default=0)

class Hotel(Document):
    code = IntField(default=0)
    nom = StringField(max_length=200)
    chambre = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Chambre))
    resume = StringField(max_length=200)
```

1 - I want a query to filter all **Hotel** that have at least a **Chambre** with prix >= a (a floeat number)

2 - also have that **Chambre**

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [embedded notatio](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#filtering-queries)n as well as the [Query Operator](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators) for "greater than or equal "

```
Hotel.objects(chambre__prix__gte=a)
```

Or if you need to cast as an integer:

```
Hotel.objects(chambre__prix__gte=int(math.floor(a)))
```

If you want to only project the "matched" element, use a raw query directly on the driver instead:

```
Hotel._get_collection().find(
  { 'chambre.prix': { '$gte': int(math.floor(a)) } },
  { 'chambre.$': 1 }
)
```

Comment: and how to have this chambre also?

Comment: @abinax No idea what you mean. Do you mean return only the entry of the array that matches the condition?

Comment: yeah, in the every **Hotel.chambre** there is chambre that have prix>a only

Comment: @abinax As to the context of the question, I believe `.fields(chambre__S=1)` does the positional match here. See above. As for anything else outside of the scope of the question you asked, then  please [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: I gor this :Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'db_field'

Comment: @abinax Try on the underlying driver collection. Added that as well. Beyond that I need to spin up an instance and test directly, which could take a while.

Comment: @abinax Okay confirmed that the only present way to do this is the last way by accessing the underlying driver, which works for me when I query. There is still an [open issue to improve this syntax](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/529), but it is 4 years old now and has not changed.